# Highcharts - Specific color zones for HighCharts navigator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

Is there a way to add color zones to the High Charts navigator ? If it doesn't fall between a zone it should have a default color. Something like, from this value to this value it has this color, otherwise it's blue.

I basically have some reporting periods that have a start and end date and a specific color. I'd like that for each reporting period to appear with their respective color on the High Charts navigator. I have it somewhat working, using zones but for zones with no reporting period it takes the color of the next one.

This is what it currently looks like. 
[image: Current status]

And here's the code:

```
const zones = reportingPeriods.map((rp, i) => {
    return {
        value: new Date(rp.endDate),
        color: rp.color
    }
})

const seriesData = _.map(graphData, (metricData, key) => {
    return {
        name: key,
        data: metricData.sort(function(a, b) {
            return a[0] - b[0];
        }),

        zoneAxis: 'x',
        zones: zones,
        tooltip: {
            valueDecimals: 0
        },

        visible: false
    }
})

const graphOptions = {
    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
    },
    navigator: {
        maskFill: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)'
    },
    backgroundColor: {
        linearGradient: [0, 0, 500, 500],
        stops: [
            [0, 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'],
            [1, 'rgb(200, 200, 255)']
        ]
    },
    title: {
        text: group.groupName
    },
    series: seriesData,
    credits: false,
    legend: {
        enabled: true
    }
}
```

Is there a way where you could define a start and end point for a zone ? and also restrict the coloring strictly to the navigator ?

Ideally it would be nice if the zones could be defined like this:

```
from: rp.startDate,
to: rp.endDate,
color: rp.color
```

Any push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've answered the questions below. [Here is the TLDR fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/mrrugbxd/).

> Is there a way where you could define a start and end point for a zone ?

The format you've suggested is invalid, but the workaround is to fill in the blanks with zones using the "default color" you want. That means changing your `map` to a more elaborate function. For example:

```
periods = [
  { start: 2,  end: 5,  color: 'green' },
  { start: 5,  end: 7,  color: 'pink' },
  { start: 10, end: 15, color: 'red' },
  { start: 19, end: 21, color: 'yellow' }
];

defaultColor = 'black';
zones = [];

for(var i = 0; i < periods.length; i++) {
  // This zone is a "in-between" zone to fill the blanks.
  zones.push({
    value: periods[i].start,
    color: defaultColor
  });

  // This zone is an actual period
  zones.push({
    value: periods[i].end,
    color: periods[i].color
  });
}

// This zone is cover the values from your last period to infinity
zones.push({
  color: defaultColor
});
```

Here I imagine the `periods` array to match your `reportingPeriods` and the `zones` array to be the end product which you apply to your series.

> and also restrict the coloring strictly to the navigator ?

To only apply the zones to the navigator you simply use the `navigator.series` object. For example:

```
navigator: {
  series: {
    type: 'line',
    zones: zones
  }
}
```

And not apply them to the actual series.

Comment: Oh you absolute legend, that works perfectly. I feel kind of stupid I didn't think about that. Thank you so much for your help.